# Django:How to get url parameters passed to views from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

This is my url pattern:

```
  url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/view/$', views.leave_view, name='leave_view')
```

my views.py

```
def leave_view(request,pk):
    leaves=leave.objects.get(id=pk);
    data=dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data['html_form']= render_to_string('m_manage/view_modal.html', {'leaves':leaves}, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

My js call
js----call to on click of button

```
<script>
    $("#table").on('click', '.view', function (e) {
        var btn = $(this);
        console.log(btn);
        var url = btn.attr("data-url");
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            // url: '/m_manage/leave_view/', 
            url: btn.attr("data-url"),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('You Did it!!!!');
                console.log(data);
                $("#modal-leave .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My console.log(data) prints nothing though I am collecting primary key from url and writing query...Why there is no data in it...

Comment: You only fill data on POST, but request it with GET.

Comment: I got you thank you so much...It worked..!